# ¿Por qué Sublime Text 3 no ejecuta estas líneas de Ruby?

Tags: ruby, matrices, sublimetext3

estoy aprendiendo a programar en Ruby utilizando Sublime Text 3 en Windows. La cosa es que estaba buscando unos ejemplos para hacer matrices con Ruby e hice este siguiendo los pasos de uno que encontré:

```
arreglo = [10, 5, 2, 20, 50]
suma = 0
    print "Arreglo completo", arreglo
    print "La suma de sus componentes es #{suma}"
puts
```

Lo anterior es un ejercicio de arreglos que estaba realizando, de aquí para abajo el código parece no funcionar cuando lo ejecuto en el programa, lo siguiente son las líneas del ejercico sobre matrices que mencioné al principio:

```
print prueba_matriz = Array.new(3, ["A"])

for i in 0...3
  for j in 0...3
    print("prueba_matrix[#{i}][#{j}]: ")
    prueba_matrix[i][j] = gets.to_i
  end
end
```

En la consola de Sublime, cuando ejecuto el código, no me aparece nada, es como si no hubiera alguna línea que funcionara, tampoco me aparece algún mensaje de error, simplemente no aparece nada y no me puedo guiar para saber que está mal.

Eso es todo el código, sin embargo cuando lo ejecuto a través del programa, como lo mencioné antes, no muestra nada, ni siquiera el código anterior a esas líneas en concreto, pero cuando borro la parte en donde inicia el primer `for` hasta el `end` correspondiente entonces se ejecuta el código correctamente, es decir si el código está de esta manera, quitándole el `for` y demás:

```
arreglo = [10, 5, 2, 20, 50]
suma = 0
    print "Arreglo completo", arreglo
    print "La suma de sus componentes es #{suma}"
puts
print prueba_matrix = Array.new(3, ["A"])
```

De la anterior forma, el código funciona y se ejecuta correctamente, pero cuando agrego la función `for` para poner algún dato en la matriz no funciona, no muestra nada y tampoco me muestra algún error. La verdad no sé qué sucede y por qué no se ejecuta el código completo. Muchas gracias por cualquier ayuda.

Comment: Hola Daniel, bienvenido. Tu código funciona correctamente, así que no me queda claro cual es el error; ¿podrías editar tu pregunta y agregar la salida del programa? También mencionas que hay código anterior a esas líneas, ¿podrías agregar el código completo?

Comment: Buenas, ya edité la pregunta, supongo que así se entiende mejor, gracias por responder y por la ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que tu código espera *input* del usuario, el cual se ingresa a través de la consola/terminal en windows, pero a través de la consola de *Sublime* no puedes ingresar el dato esperado.

Por lo tanto, no podrás utilizar el *Build* de *Sublime* para probar código que necesite interacción en la consola (probablemente a través de un *plugin*).

Para probar lo anterior, cambia el `gets.to_i` por un valor generado dentro del mismo programa; por ejemplo:

```
prueba_matriz = Array.new(3) { Array.new(3, ["A"]) }
puts prueba_matriz.inspect

contador = 0

for i in 0...3
  for j in 0...3
    print("prueba_matriz[#{i}][#{j}]: ")
    prueba_matriz[i][j] = contador += 1
  end
end

puts prueba_matriz.inspect
```

Notarás algunos cambios con respecto a tu código, estos son simplemente para dar mayor legibilidad al resultado excepto por la definición de la matriz, en la que es necesario declarar otro  `Array.new` para evitar que se sobreescriba la información de cada *celda*.

Comment: Muchas gracias, no sabía que esperaba una respuesta del usuario, de nuevo gracias.